# $\pi_2(T \vee \mathbb{C}P^2)$ and action of $\pi_1$ on $\pi_2$

Tags: homotopy-theory, group-actions, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, fibration

Let $X= T \vee \mathbb{C}P^2,$ where $ T$ denotes the 2-dimensional torus.

The task is to compute $\pi_2(X)$ and describe the action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\pi_2(X)$.

As for the first part, is there any appropriate Serre fibration I could write long exact sequence for? Homotopy groups are known not behave well regarding wedge products. On the other hand, how could on compute homotopy groups of universal cover ([Universal cover of $T^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564937/universal-cover-of-t2-vee-mathbbrp2)) - is it simply connected and thus by Hurewicz theorem: $\pi_2(X)\approx\pi_2(\widetilde{X})\approx H_2(\widetilde{X})$. Secondly, how to describe action of $\pi_1$ on higher homotopy groups? Is not a path-connected space the space where the fundamental group acts trivially on all homotopy groups?

Answer (score 3):

You're right about the universal cover, so you should try to describe it *explicitly* to understand its $H_2$.

Then for the action of $\pi_1(X)$, note the following result:

> Let $X$ be a nice  connected space with universal cover $\tilde X$. Then there is a nice action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\tilde X$. This induces an action on $\pi_2(\tilde X)$ : with the isomorphism $\pi_2(\tilde X)\cong \pi_2(X)$, this is exactly the action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\pi_2(X)$

Note that this is not well stated : indeed homotopy groups require basepoints, and the action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\tilde X$ does not preserve them, so as such, the action on $\pi_2(\tilde X)$ not well-defined.

But $\tilde X$ is simply-connected, so $\pi_2(\tilde X, x)$ and $\pi_2(\tilde X, y)$ are canonically isomorphic, via any path $x\to y$ in $\tilde X$.

Therefore if you're precise you can state this result correctly, and with the correct statement it becomes almost obvious.

But then you can compute this action on $\pi_2(\tilde X)$ via the same action on $H_2(\tilde X)$ by Hurewicz, and with a geometric understanding of $\tilde X$ (and of why its homology is what it is), you'll get a geometric understanding of the action on $H_2(\tilde X)\cong \pi_2(\tilde X)\cong \pi_2(X)$